# How can I get rid of unused MATE panel icons/indicators?

Tags: icons, panel, mate, ubuntu-mate

I have 3 icons in my Ubuntu 18.04 MATE top panel. I can't get rid of them but they do nothing. The image below shows just part of the top panel containing the circular images.

[image: up/down arrow, number 9 and capital A icons in top panel]

One contains a vertical line with up and down arrowheads, the middle one contains the numeral 9 and the right one contains a capital A.  How do I get rid of them and do they serve any purpose?

Comment: Those look like keyboard indicator buttons.  The first on the left is for Scroll Lock.  The middle one is for NumLock.  And the last one is for CAPS Lock.